# Simulate multiple cluster nodes, using python sockets

Tags: python, virtual-machine, python-sockets

I understand within sockets you can bind a socket to an address and have sockets on the same machine connect to it, server to client style. However, I want to run a distributed compute style so each machine will have its own open port, which leads to the problem of assigning to the same address which can't be done. E.g. All nodes will have an open port 2000, then once the connection is established be moved to a different port using sockets functionality.

My question is, is there a way I can simulate this behavior without having to use full-on virtual machines? I have gone about creating classes in multiple threads but the handling of mutual exclusion and creating my own fake sockets class has made the project very difficult.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Assign random ports and have your simulated nodes register themselves with a registration service? Run your code inside multiple containers (a container has its own ip address, so you can happily have many things listening on the same port...on different addresses)? Create multiple ips on your host and bind your listeners to specific addresses? There are lots of ways to solve this sort of thing.

Comment: I completely didn't even think about the first idea, thank you